# Python regex to detect one of multiple optional substrings following a string

Tags: python, regex

I need to match patterns like the following: `AAXX#`

Where:
* `AA` is from a set (ie. a `list`) of 1-3 char alpha prefixes,
* `XX` is from a different list of pre-defined strings, and
* `any single-digit numeral` follows.

AA strings: `['bo','h','fr','sam','pe']`

XX strings: `cl` + `['x','n','r','nr','eaner]` //OR ELSE JUST// `ro`

Desired Result: bool indicating whether any of the possible combos match the provided string.

Sample Test Strings:
`item = "boro1"` - that is, `bo` + `ro` + `1`
`item = "samcl2"`- i.e. `sam` + `cl` + `2`
`item = "hcln3"` - i.e. `h` + `cln` + `3`

The best I can figure is to use a loop, but I am having trouble with the essential regex. It works for the single-letter optionals `cln, clx, clr`, but not for the longer ones `clnr, cleaner`.

### Code:

```
item = "hclnr2" #h + clnr + 2
out = False
arr = ['bo','h','fr','sam','pe']
for mnrl in arr:
    myrx = re.escape(mnrl) + r'cl[x|n|r|nr|eaner]\d'
    thisone = bool(re.search(myrx, item))
    print('mnrl: '+mnrl+' - ', thisone)
    if thisone: out = True

##########################################################################
# SKIP THIS - INCLUDED IN CASE S/O HAS A BETTER SOLUTION THAN A SECOND LOOP
# THE ABOVE FOR-LOOP handled THE CL[opts] TESTS, THIS LOOP DOES THE RO TESTS
##########################################################################
#if not out: #If not found a match amongst the "cl__" options, test for "ro"
#    for mnrl in arr:
#        myrx = re.escape(mnrl) + r'ro\d'
#        thisone = bool(re.search(myrx, item))
#        print('mnrl: '+mnrl+' - ', thisone)
#    if thisone: out = True
##########################################################################

print('result: ', out)
```

### PRINTS:

`mnrl: bo -  False`
`mnrl: h -  False <======` 
`mnrl: fr -  False`
`mnrl: sam -  False`
`mnrl: pe -  False`

#### However, changing `item` to:

```
item = "hcln2" #h + cln + 2
```

PRINTS:
`mnrl: bo -  False`
`mnrl: h -  True <========` 
`mnrl: fr -  False`
`mnrl: sam -  False`
`mnrl: pe -  False`

And ditto for `item = hclr5` or `item = hclx9` BUT NOT `hcleaner9`

Comment: Per the explanation, `samcl2` shouldn't be matching (should return false). Or can XX strings be `cl` alone (without anything following it)?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The answer is Yes, `cl` alone is enough to make the output True. So, `samcl2` should be True. Merely `cl` by itself, is False, as is `cl#` without one of the desired prefixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be

```
import re

words = ['boro1', 'samcl2', 'hcln3', 'boro1+unwantedstuff']

p = r'(bo|h|fr|sam|pe)(cl(x|n|r|nr|eaner|)|ro)\d$'

for w in words:
      print(re.match(p, w))
```

Result:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='boro1'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='samcl2'>    
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='hcln3'>
None
```

For your desired boolean output you can simply cast the match object to 'bool'.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the misconceptions in your code include the usage of character classes (syntax: `[ ... ]`). When you use a character class, any single character from the character class will try to match the string (with the exception where a few other characters are used, these characters being `^` and `-` when placed in specific positions). This means that:

```
[x|n|r|nr|eaner]
```

Will match any one character among: x, |, n, r, e, a (duplicated characters are essentially being discarded)

I'm not entirely sure why you are doing all those intricate things like `re.escape` in your code, I trust you can understand the snippet below to adapt it to your situation:

```
import re

def matchPattern(item, extract=False):
    result = re.match(r"(bo|h|fr|sam|pe)((?:cl(?:nr|eaner|[xnr]|))|ro)([0-9])$", item)
    if result:
        if extract:
            return (result.group(1), result.group(2), result.group(3))
        else:
            return True
    else:
        if extract:
            return ('','','')
        else:
            return False
```

I tweaked the `def` a little such that you get a boolean if you call for example `matchPattern("boro1")`, and if you want to get the substring components, you can call `matchPattern("boro1", True)` and you will get `('bo', 'ro', '1')` as result (or `('', '', '')` if it doesn't match)

As for the regex itself, you can test it on [here](https://regex101.com/r/wTudYb/2) (regex101.com)

You need to use groups if you want to use the `|` regex operator. In the regex I use above,

- `(bo|h|fr|sam|pe)` means either one of bo, h, fr, sam or pe
- `((?:cl(?:nr|eaner|[xnr]|))|ro)` means either `(?:cl(?:nr|eaner|[xnr]|))` (this means cl followed by either nr, eaner, x, n, r or nothing) or ro
- `([0-9])` means a number (I prefer this to `\d` for minor additional performance)